# Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) 64-bit and ODBC

Tags: oracle, odbc

I have Windows 64-bit, Office 32-bit and I downloaded "Oracle Database 18c Express Edition for Windows x64" (Oracle Database Express Edition (XE) Release 18.4.0.0.0 (18c)) from this site https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html.
I want to configure ODBC because of connecting Excel with Oracle DB.

My question is how is it possible to add driver "Oracle in OraDB18Home1" into ODBC Data Source Administrator (32-bit)? This driver is visible only in ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit) - picture below.

If it is not possible (I guess that ODBC 64-bit will not work with Excel 32-bit) could you give me link for official download " Oracle Database 18c Express Edition for Windows **x32**"? I do not see 32-bit version of Oracle Express Edition on official site.

Thank you for answer or explanation of my problem.

[image]

Comment: Oracle does not release any 32-bit Oracle Database *server*  since Oracle 12.1 released in June 2013.

Comment: It doesn't matter that the database is 64 bit.  What matters is the client that the app (excel) binds to.  You will need the 32-bit oracle client, installed in its own ORACLE_HOME, and including the odbc driver.  ODBC itself is not a substitute for a native database client.  It simply acts as a middle-man between the native database client and the end-user application.

Comment: If your Excel is 32-bit then you have to install also the 32-bit Oracle Client/ODBC. You cannot mix it. The database does not matter (as already written by EdStevens). If you like to install both, 32-bit and 64-bit Oracle Client, follow this instruction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100

Answer (score 2):

Go to this [link](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/microsoft-windows-32-downloads.html) scroll down to `Development and Runtime - optional packages` and download ODBC package.That zip file has `ODBC_INSTALL.EXE` install and you will see oracle drivers from ODBC 32 bit  and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for me was to do a completely new installation of Oracle 32-bit with 32-bit Client. Thank you @EdStevens and @Wernfried Domscheit.